# Troubleshooting intermittent server connection

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-server-2003

My network has around 50 Windows 7 PCs and two Windows 2003 servers (SERVER1, SERVER2). Many of the clients are having an intermittent problem connecting to SERVER2. The clients are unable to connect to network shares, pinging will time out and connecting via explorer ("\SERVER2") will fail. A few minutes later the client will connect fine and ping in <1ms.

Errors I have seen include:

- Cannot reconnect. Local device name is already in use
- Windows can't communicate with the device or resource
- Error 0x80004005 windows cannot access

It doesn't seem to make any difference if the device and the server are attached to the same switch or if the packets have to go through several switches, between buildings or over Wifi.

I'm struggling to see where to even start troubleshooting. What logs should I look in? Are there any tools I can run to analyse the connections?

Answer (score 0):

This could be possible due to multiple environmental factors. Please try to isolate and check the outcome.

1. Check your security software settings such as Firewall, Antivirus and etc.
2. Change the switch where the clients are connected. Generally it is not recommended to connect servers and clients in the same switch.
3. Check the cables which are connected to the servers.
4. Ensure, the same subnet is not assigned to multiple network cards of the server.
5. Ensure, Server IP range is not assigned to the clients. This may create conflict while you use DHCP setup.